# Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

Im absolutely a beginner in React Native, Redux, and friends.

Now I try to create an app with React Native and Redux.

In the process I found this error :

[image]

I try to use Redux in my app like this :

```js
export const confirmRegister = (userdata) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return(
            fetch(URI + path, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'x-application-id' : AppId,
                    'hashing' : this.generateHashing(userdata)
                },
                body: userdata,
            })
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then((response)=>{
                dispatch(setDataAfterRegister(response.result))
            })
            .catch(error => {alert(error)})
        )
      };
    };

    export function setDataAfterRegister(data){
      return{
        type:'REGISTERED',
        name:data.name,
        token:data.access_token
      }
    }
```

I'm still learning how to use Redux.

Any helps will be really appreciated.

Here's my store:

```js
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers';
 
let store = createStore(rootReducer);
 
export default store;
```

Comment: have you setup redux-thunk?

Comment: no, I don't have redux-thunk in my app

Comment: show how you create your redux store.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`confirmRegister` function returns a function:

```
export const confirmRegister = (userdata) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
```

Redux don't know how to handle it natively. You need a middleware to do that. Most popular middleware that will let you return a function from your action creators is a [redux-thunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk).

First install it:

```
npm install --save redux-thunk
```

and then set up middleware:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me :D... one more, how do I catch the updated state ?

Comment: @kurniawan26 No problem. If you want to access current state use react-redux and `connect`

Comment: it works, now I want to `navigate` to home screen after the states updated, I got this `warning` when Im on the home screen : `Warning:Cannot update during an existing state transition` any idea ?

Comment: @kurniawan26 you probably try to update unmounted component.

Comment: sorry, I dont get your point sir.. is this something I really need to fix ? or I can just ignore the `warning` ?

Comment: @kurniawan26 it's a warning, not an error so it's "only" recommended to fix it. That would be a topic for another question. You probably will find a lot of similar questions on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Your Action creator `confirmRegister` returns a function, But in React action creator returns a action that is a plain JS Object.

So you need some middleware to tell react about this asynchronous call. 
You can use `Redux-thunk` , `redux-Sagas` and other middlewares. 
This will let your action creator return a function and that function on getting response will dispatch a  new action object.

You can install the middlerware using `npm` or `yarn`

```
npm install --save redux-thunk
yarn add redux-thunk
```

Add that to your store config file.

And for that `Warning:Cannot update during an existing state transition`
you have to setState of a component either in `ComponentWillReceiveProps` or `ComponentWillMount`. You are probably setting the state in `render` method.
`

Comment: where should I call `ComponentWillReceiveProps` ? is it on my current screen or on the screen that I want to navigate to ?

Comment: The Current Screen from which you want navigation to happen

Comment: woaaaaaahhhh... thank you so much.. the warning dissapear.. I wish you have a good day sir